# Nodejs callback with bad workflow

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm new with NODE and I'm trying this code:

```
require('../../constants.js');

function dbConnect() {
    var mysql       = require('mysql');
    var connection  = mysql.createConnection({
        host        : DB_HOST,
        database    : DB_NAME,
        user        : DB_USER,
        password    : DB_PASS,
    });
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ...");

    });
    return connection;

}

function dbDisconnect(connection) {
    connection.end();
    console.log("Closing DB Connection");
}

function findPlayer(surname) {
    var connection = dbConnect(); 
    console.log("Finding -> " + surname);
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE surname = "' + surname + '"';
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) 
    {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i in rows) {
            console.log('Players: ', rows[i].surname);
        }   
    });

    dbDisconnect(connection);   

}

exports.findPlayer = findPlayer;
```

After that, I've a laucher file:

```
require('./constants.js');
var aar = require('./libs/DBManager.js')
console.log('Loading DBManager');    
var player = aar.findPlayer('Potter');    
console.log(player);
```

Correct workflow is:

- Loading DBManager
- Database is connected...
- Finding -> Potter
- Players: Potter
- Closing DB Connection

However the result is:

- Loading DBManager
- Finding -> Potter
- Closing DB Connection
- undefined
- Database is connected...
- Players: Potter

What's my wrong? Is some callback issue?

Comment: Please specify the file names also, the explanation is a bit confusing. But one thing you need to consider is, connect to db is Async, so when u request a connection to db Node.js moves ahead and execute the next statement. Therefore you are getting database connected message later

Comment: First part of code was libs/DBManager.js, and the second is index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing your connection before your query is for sure done. 
you should put the `dbDisconnect(connection);` after the end of the query but inside the callback.

```
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) 
    {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i in rows) {
            console.log('Players: ', rows[i].surname);
        }  
       dbDisconnect(connection); 
    });
```

also the findPlayer is not returning anything, so the `console.log(player);` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is Async in nature, it doesn't wait for I/O operations. Any network call including request to connect to a DB comes under I/O operations.

The problem is that you are requesting a DB connection and before it is returned, you are making call to get data for players. I suggest you pass a callback method to the

```
dbConnect(callback)
```

And in that callback, you pass the query or operation you want to execute:

1. Create a callback method that contains the code to retrieve the **players** information
2. Call **dbConnect()** to establish the connection to DB and pass the callback as an argument
3. After connection is established, execute the callback
4. After you are done, you can close the connection, but make sure the code to close the connection, is with in the callback and is executed only after you received the data from Db

On the contrary if you are comfortable with ORM, i suggest you try [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), it abstracts out the requirement to create and disconnect connections with DB, so you can focus on your crud operations.

Comment: Please could you give me a sample of code about it?